# Evaluating $3^{a-1}$

Tags: exponential-function

> If 
>   $$3^{-a}=2$$
>   Evaluate 
>   $$3^{a-1} $$

**Here's my attempt:**

$$3^{-a}=2$$

Rewriting the equation

$$3^{a}=2^{-1} \implies 3^{a-1} = 2^{-2} = \dfrac 1 4$$

Regards!

Comment: you were almost there ...just multiply both side by 1/3

Answer (score 4):

Not quite

If $3^{a}=2^{-1}$

then you need to divide both sides by $3$

to get $3^{a-1}$ on the left hand side

and the answer on the right hand side

Comment: Where can I find similiar examples on textbooks? I've recently taken a look at an algebra book. However, I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there
$$3^{a}=2^{-1} \implies 3^{a-1} = 2^{-2} = \dfrac 1 4$$
note that 
$$3^{a-1}=3^a \times 3^{-1}= \frac {3^a}3= {3^a}\times \frac 13$$
So multiply both side by 1/3

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem using logarithm as well?

Comment: @Maxwell you don't need that here...you did almost all the job except for the last step

Comment: How do I need to search it on textbooks in order to find similar examples? I couldn't see any.

Comment: @maxwell try google search "exercices solutions  fractions power "  ...you should find what you need...that's what I do when I need specific exercices